# Replace html characters with "" (blank) and apply styling to text within

Tags: java, android, regex, string, replace

I have a string like this:

```
String s="12 year old Manick is &lt;b&gt;three&lt;/b&gt; times as old as his brother Rahul. How old will Manick be when he is twice as old as Rahul ?";
```

When I set this string to a TextView, the output is like this:

[image: output]

**What I want is, the output to be like this:**

12 year old Manick is **three** times as old as his brother Rahul. How old will Manick be when he is twice as old as Rahul ?

**What should be done to the original string to get the desired output in the TextView?**

Actually, my requirement is to extract the text inside the HTML tags, apply the bold formatting to the text inside the tag and remove the tags from the string before displaying in the TextView.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: The string is coming from an XML file, so it may vary!

Comment: are you getting the text dynamically or statically?

Comment: dynamically from parsing XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try defining your text for the TextView in strings.xml.Then if you set from html then it may wrap according to screen size:

So you can try this out:

```
<string name="nice_html">
<![CDATA["12 year old Manick is &lt;b&gt;three&lt;/b&gt; times as old as his brother Rahul. How old will Manick be when he is twice as old as Rahul ?";
]]></string>
```

Then, in your code:

```
TextView foo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foo); foo.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.nice_html)));
```

**EDIT:**

just change the last code to

```
//string s already defined in the question

TextView foo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foo); 
foo.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(s)));
```

Comment: That can not be done as the String is coming from XML files. Its not static!

Comment: glad to help.. you're in kolkata? why dont you add me on gtalk or some messenger?